# IDE can't resolve writeValue() method for Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jackson

All my life I worked with C++, but recently decided to play a bit with Java. I have started with learning Jackson serialier/desirialer library. The basic example looks like that

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/car.json"), car);
```

It looks pretty easy and no problems should arise here. My IDE is IntelliJ, so before running the code I used Maven to get next libraries

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4
```

Taking into account that class `Car` is implemented somewhere above it should now work. However when I try to build the code I get an error that compiler can't resolve the symbol `writeValue()`. Autocomplition faces the same problem. My first assumption is that not all external libraries are correclty resolved, but when I open the source code for `ObjectMapper` in IDE I clearly see method `writeValue()`. Even more if I try to call this method just after the creating object with operator `new` autocomplition is able to recognize it. If I remove the line with
`writeValue()` call code successfully compiles. 
From C++ prospective it looks like madness, so please suggest why it happens and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Could you also show your `pom.xml` file? Could you try to build it in console/terminal by `mvn clean install` in folder where `pom.xml` file is?

Comment: Seems like I don't have `pom.xml` file. I just created a new project and added libraries with IntelliJ `ProjectStructure->Libraries->NewProjectLibrary(from Maven)`.

Comment: It means this is not properly created Maven project. In Java general rule that all needed jars should be on class path. You have to read first about that and how to properly create project in your IDE with or without Maven. But I would recommend use Maven it boosts Java developing. This is not a problem with `Jackson` library.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: Creating a maven project with `pom.xml` file solved a problem. Thanks! I will also try to fix my initial project with provided guide.